# where to place my own google emulated classes?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

This is my current setup

```
src/
    com
        acme
            Model.gwt.xml   
            model
                token
                    Token.java
    ...
test/
super
    com
        acme
            jre
                java
                    lang
                        CloneNotSupportedException.java (introducing class since GWT doesnt support it)
        google              
            gwt
                emul
                    java
                        lang
                            Character.java (added a method that GWT doesn't support)
```

the super source path in Model.gwt.xml

is

`super-source path="jre"`

when I compile, the compiler complains about errors in both my emulated classes

> Errors in....Token.java
>
> ...isWhitespace(char) is undefined for
>   the type Character ...No source code
>   is available for type
>   java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;

It appears its not picking up the things I emulated.

Following the GWT documentation I have also tried taking "jre" folder in to src/com/acme/, ie literally in the same level has the module xml. But doesnt work.

I read in a post that google's emul is picked up itself hence I put both jre and google's stuff in super, but only included "jre" as super source

I am using gwt-maven-plugin to compile and my pom.xml excerpt is

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of compile errors from super source in eclipse, just modify your java build path; in whatever source folder you have your emulated code, put in an excludes filter such as `**/jre/**/*.java` or `**/emul/**/*.java`.  This will keep the ide happy, while gwt developer mode and compiles will both have the emulated super-source on it's classpath.

Oh, and I noticed you're using maven, not eclipse.  Just exclude your emulated package in the maven-source-plugin.  That way maven compiler never sees emulated files, and the source package is still complete for gwt: goals.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <value>**/emul/**/*.java</value>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

### A tip for IDE users (tried in Eclipse)

To ensure that the aforementioned exclusion filters persist between Maven project updates/imports, add an `<excludes>` to your Maven compiler plugin configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <value>**/emul/**/*.java</value>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is because you are probably still running in developer mode.  The code you have done above should work when you GWT compile and deploy your application.